# How can I open an app with arguments in ChromeOS?

Tags: google-chrome-os, google-chrome-flags

I need to use this Chrome argument,

`--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`

on Windows you simply add that to the shortcut on your Desktop.
But I can't seem to find a way on ChromeOS, any idea?